# Редактирование текстового файла произвольного размера в C/C++

Tags: c, c++

Надо удалить(вырезать) первый символ файла **не создавая новый файл**. Подскажите реально ли это? Как обрезать конец файла разобрался, а вот обрезать начало не получается.

```
Пример: Есть файл.тхт = (0123456789) и он содержит 10 байт, надо вырезать первый символ (0-ноль). 
Конечный результат: файл.тхт = (123456789) и он содержать уже 9 байт
```

Это функция обрезает конец файла на 1 байт, может кто то сможет её адаптировать

```
int urez(long l){//l-размер файла
int fh;
fh=open("1.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
chsize(fh,l-1); //1 - 1 символ будет вырезан с конца
close(fh);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так с или с++? Или без разницы? А что именно не получается при адаптации примера из ответа на предыдущий вопрос?

Comment: Без разницы с или с++. В предыдущий вопрос была замена символа, а здесь удаление(+ уменьшение файла на 1 байт)

Comment: 1. Пропустить N байт.
2. Прочитать остальные данные до EOF.
3. Записать их по смещению 0.

Всё-таки, что именно не получается?

Comment: В порядке бредогенерации - если перформанс настолько критичен, то можете попробовать напрямую обратиться к inod'у файловой системы и скажем подменить начальный сектор для файла. Не знаю, можно ли такие вещи стабильно реализовать, но, мне кажется, что для всех остальных случаев можно доказать что без покусочного копирования файла не обойтись. mmap, естественно, задачу не решает.

Comment: Таки есть хорошее решение (правда, платформо-зависимое) - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/01/10097859.aspx

Comment: Либо банально враппить stream на client-side, который при чтении будет пропускать N первых символов - если физическое представление файла не столь принципиально, а важен только user interaction.

Comment: @Asen2, в комментарии "бредогенерации" Вы по сути советуете изменить код ядра.

--

В комментарии с ссылкой (http://blogs.msdn.com...) Вы имеете в виду файлы с "дырами" (делаем, например write,lseek-далеко,write)? В \*nix они тоже есть. В приведенной Вами ссылке разжевывается, почему это **не универсальное решение**. На самом деле несколько (один) байт в начале так не удалить (даже с целью экономии места на диске). Можно ли удалить первый блок файла целиком? IMHO зависит от системы.

--

Третий комментарий вообще не по теме. Разве у кого-то есть проблема в передаваче данных не с начала файла?

Answer (score 3):

Как сделать без ftruncate() не знаю. Если волнует Windows, то в MinGW он есть.

Обещал mmap (делал в linux), привожу:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MY_TRUNC_BSIZE 4096000

int
shift_file_left (char *fname, off_t len)
{
  if (!len)
    return 0;
  if (len < 0) {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return EX_DATAERR;
  }

  char *p = NULL;
  int fd = open(fname,O_RDWR), rc = 1;
  if (fd < 0)
    return EX_NOINPUT;

  do {
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fd,&st);
    if (st.st_size <= len) {
      rc = ftruncate(fd,0);
      break;
    }
#ifdef USE_MMAP

    if (!(p = mmap(NULL,st.st_size,PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0)))
      break;
    if (rc = madvise(p,st.st_size,MADV_SEQUENTIAL))
      break;
    memcpy(p,p+len,st.st_size-len);
    rc = munmap(p,st.st_size);

#else

    if (!(p = malloc(MY_TRUNC_BSIZE)))
      break;
    int  fr = open(fname,O_RDONLY);
    ssize_t l;
    if (fr < 0)
      break;
    if (lseek(fr,len,SEEK_SET) == -1) {
      close (fr);
      break;
    }
    while ((l = read(fr,p,MY_TRUNC_BSIZE)) > 0) {
      if ((l = write(fd,p,l)) < 0)
        break;
    }
    close(fr);
    if (l < 0)
      break;

#endif
    rc = ftruncate(fd,st.st_size-len);
  } while (0);

#ifndef USE_MMAP
  if (p)
    free(p);
#endif
  close (fd);
  return rc? EX_OSERR: EX_OK;
}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac < 3) {
    fprintf (stderr,"Usage (shift_left): %s file-name length\n",
         av[0]);
    exit (EX_USAGE);
  }
  int  rc;

  if (rc = shift_file_left(av[1],atol(av[2])))
    perror("shift_file_left");

  exit (rc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм примерно такой. Открываем файл для чтения. Считываем из него содержимое в буфер. Закрываем файл. Делаем с содержимым буфера, что надо. Открываем опять файл для записи с очисткой содержимого (в случае fopen с параметром "w"). Записываем содержимое буфера в файл. Закрываем его. Имеем файл с новым содержимым.

Comment: файл произвольного размера, на 1 Gb мне что 3 часа ждать чтобы вырезал 1 символ?

Comment: @Feodor, делайте через open,mmap и ftruncate. 

Сейчас некогда, пример напишу позже.

Comment: я буду ждать ))))

Comment: @avp, а Вы уверены, что у него POSIX-совместимая система? Тут, конечно, интересно придумать кроссплатформенное решение. Если используется С++, то можно использовать boost::filesystem::resize_file() для изменения размера файла.

Comment: нет не совместима, у меня не будет работать ftruncate

Comment: Вообще, универсальный алгоритм заключается в том, чтобы небольшие файлы целиком запихивать в память и там обрабатывать, а большие либо редактировать в живьем (долго и муторно) либо все использовать временные файлы: считывать исходный по кусочкам, налету редактировать и записывать во временный файл.

Comment: > файл произвольного размера, на 1 Gb мне что 3 часа ждать чтобы вырезал 1 символ?

Вот поэтому я и воздержался от поспешных ответов. Меня вот что волнует. Ведь когда мы вырезаем символ, то нам придется все последующие сдвинуть. Либо надо сказать операционке, что у нас исчез кусок файла. Иначе неизбежать сдвига всего оставшегося хвостика :-(

Comment: @gecube, сомневаюсь, что есть возможность, даже при отображении в страничную память.

Comment: Без сдвига "хвостика" не обойтись. Просто mmap позволяет двигать его прямо в буферах файловой системы.

Comment: Дак тогда за мемсру будет скрываться самое обычное копирование хвоста файла. Красивый вариант, но память будет использоваться нерационально.

Comment: @karmado4, какую память Вы имеете в виду ?

Физические страницы не дублируются. mmap добавляет страницы виртуальной памяти процесса, которые отображаются на страницы кэша файловой системы. В любом случае при чтении файла его данные попадают в кэш. Дополнительная память расходуется только на таблицы страниц процесса.

Механизм пэйджинга и заполнения-освобождения файлового кэша в *nix согласован. Политику чтения-замещения маппированных страниц можно выбрать, вызывая madvise().

Вы программку посмотрите.

Comment: @avp, половину страницы ну никак нельзя :-) Даже самая экономичная политика будет держать закоммиченными в адр. пространство 2 страницы. В то время, как кондовая реализация с перекладыванием частей файла с помощью буфера будет использовать только N байт буфера.

Comment: @karmadro4, N байт буфера + столько страниц в кэше, сколько сочтет возможным или необходимым (и при mmap в кэше будет столько же).